# Reusable object-literals

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object

I have some **component with a table** which has actions buttons. When clicking on the button, the component emits an action, for example: (edit, delete,route)

```
getEvent(action: ActionButtons, object: any) {
    // type: (edit,delete,route), route: info where to redirect
    const {type, route} = action;
    this.action.emit({ type, route, body: object });
}
```

In the parent component I catch this object by the following function and do some logic depending on the action:

```
getAction({type, route, body: {...faculty }}) {
    const action = {
        edit: () => {
            this.openFacultyModal(faculty);
        },
        delete: () => {
            this.openConfirmDialog(faculty);
        },
        route: () => {
            this.redirecTo(faculty.faculty_id);
        }
    };
    action[type]();
}
```

The poblem is, if I want to use the table in another component I have to cut and paste `getAction()` and just change the function inside object.

It turns out that there will be code duplication.

Is it possible to somehow solve the problem of code duplication using closures or creating a separate class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your action map object reusable:

```
const actions = {
  edit(target, faculty) {
    target.openFacultyModal(faculty);
  },
  delete(target, faculty) {
    target.openConfirmDialog(faculty);
  },
  route(target, faculty) {
    target.redirecTo(faculty.faculty_id);
  }
};
```

Then use it where necessary, for instance in `getAction`:

```
getAction({type, route, body: {...faculty }}) {
  actions[type](this, faculty);
}
```

Comment: What if I need to call other functions in these actions?
For example:


`const actions = {
  edit(target, faculty) {
    target.openSubjectModal(faculty);
  };`

Comment: @ЛюбчикКочан - I think at that point what they're doing is different enough you're not duplicating code anymore. I mean, you *could* further parameterize `actions`, passing in the functions to call in the branches, but to me that's getting overcomplicated.